# Why are the Hot Network questions so weird?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Stack Overflow is a fabulous technical resource. Thanks to all responsible for setting it up, and to the entire user community that supports it! Please may I ask you though, why the hot network questions are so weird.

I understand that Stack Overflow is not merely for technical subjects like computing, maths, etc. and comes in all sorts of flavours, but I don't believe that the hot network questions are really indicative of what's on most people's minds at any one time.

I realise that they're not suggestions for other questions I may be interested in (the answers to) either, but I'm always amused when I look up some obscure syntax in some bizarre programming language to find that the hot network questions are things I could never have predicted.

I might expect:

> What is the key size currently used by RSA and Diffie-Hellman for secure communication over Internet?

Or,

> Given a Tree generate its Prüfer Code

I wouldn't expect:

> What reasons may Donald Trump have had for firing FBI Director James Comey?

But I think it's fair enough, I can imagine a lot of people asking that.

And even for other topics, (say French), I might expect things like:

> Confusion over use of « avoir » vs « être »

But what about:

> How could an apocalypse kill off all adults -- leaving only those under the age of 18?

Or:

> How did Vader restart his suit by himself so quickly?

Did anyone really ask that, ever?

Comment: I guess it must be because there are more people who like "weirder" stuff than you do than you expected.

Comment: 'How could an apocalypse kill off all adults -- leaving only those under the age of 18?' - in our world, PHP.

Comment: [related meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)

Comment: It is a *network*, SO is only a part of it.  The bottom of the page lists all the sites of the network.  Intention is certainly to draw traffic to sites less-well visited, SO is rarely featured.

Comment: Check this page out that lists all the hot questions https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot

Comment: The SE network is not restricted to technical fields. If it annoys you, I think there are several ways to turn the notifications off

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize when I made my earlier comment that you didn't realize that those questions were not from Stack Overflow. Questions like that would definitely be weird here, and would quickly be closed as off-topic.

Comment: in case if you expect the hot list to have more questions of Stack Overflow kind - don't. A while ago system has been tweaked in such a way that even when SO question gets into the list it is strongly pushed out of it after 7-8 hours ([refer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250154/165773) if you're interested in boring technical details of how this tweak works)

Comment: This question should be featured on the Hot Network Questions :) Needs more upvotes!

Comment: You think that Worldbuilding question is weird? How about the one featured on Hot two days ago, [Solid Material Made From Human Blood](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/80301/solid-material-made-from-human-blood).  My answer on that one double-tapped the daily reputation cap, probably *due* to being featured/hot. Although my personal-favorite answer was one on [building a bridge to the stars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34279/building-a-bridge-to-the-stars/34307#34307) because I accidentally discovered the speed of sound inside neutron star material.

Comment: @Don'tPanic If the OP had realised the hot questions were from different websites, they'd have asked on MSE rather than MSO, obviously.

Comment: @MrLister I seem to have developed kind of a bad habit of making inappropriate assumptions recently.

Comment: If you want to get rid of them because they don't interest you or distract you, then install the [Stack Overflow Extras](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) project. It has loads of other really useful features as well.

Answer (score 17):

Well to take your examples:

[How could an apocalypse kill off all adults -- leaving only those under the age of 18?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/80439/how-could-an-apocalypse-kill-off-all-adults-leaving-only-those-under-the-age)

It comes from wordbuilding.se which is a site (quote from their page):

> Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for
>   writers, artists and others using science, geography and culture to
>   construct imaginary worlds and settings.

[How did Vader restart his suit by himself so quickly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159234/how-did-vader-restart-his-suit-by-himself-so-quickly)

Comes from scifi.se which is (quote again):

> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is a question and answer site
>   for science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts.

Both question sounds very on topic for their respective site goal, as the hot network questions are selected from all se sites (list here: https://stackexchange.com/) with a [quite complex formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) it's not that surprising you see things you would never have asked yourself if you're not interested in those particular sites scopes.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, there's some stuff on there that you may not care to see. Other people have pointed out why; here's one option to ameliorate it.

I use a custom CSS with entries like this

```
#hot-network-questions li > div[class$="worldbuilding"],
#hot-network-questions li > a[href^="https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com"] {
    display : none !important;
}
```

for the sites that I got tired of looking at in the HNQ sidebar. It makes my browsing much happier. Give it a try.

Comment: Ehm, do we really require `!important` to make it work? In that case, I must say it's not designed very well.

Comment: CSS is not at all my area of expertise, @MrLister, but yes, I couldn't get the elements to actually be hidden without that. Any suggestions for alternatives/improvement are welcome.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Extras](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) has an option to turn it off, amongst other things.

Comment: I don't mind them. I don't want to NOT see them. I stated that they amused me.
It was just that I didn't believe they were particularly "hot" in that they weren't indicative of what's on most people's minds at any one time. 

I was just trying to get to the bottom of how "hotness" was computed - which apparently a lot of other people have asked, and answered before. I'm not sure why I've been downvoted 11 times for asking this.

Maybe I was being a bit harsh in asking "Did anyone ask that ever?" about the Vader question.